# Need to call stored procedure from lightswitch - but cannot add SqlClient reference

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I need to call a simple SQL stored procedure from Lightswitch.  I have tried to follow the instructions given by Microsoft here:

[Microsoft instructions on executing a stored procedure from Lightswitch](http://tinyurl.com/otj83fm)

However this won't work for me because I cannot see `System.Data.SqlClient` or add it as a reference.  (There is simply no `References` dialog anywhere in my VS2012 lightswitch solution, so anything to do with adding references is a non-starter.  I have no idea why References aren't showing up as I use them in other non-lightswitch projects all the time.)

It should not be this difficult.  Are the MS instructions wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

I heard that you are supposed to use a WCF RIA service and call that to exec the stored procedure, however if that's the case why do the MS instructions say otherwise? (above)

Please can somebody tell me very simply how to execute a stored procedure from Lightswitch, bearing in mind I cannot see `References` and I cannot see `System.Data.SqlClient` and the MS instructions appear to be wrong.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: The `References` don't show up in VB.Net based Lightswitch projects.  They show in C# projects fine.  But in neither can I use `System.Data.SqlClient` in any code.

Answer (score 1):

To see and add references, you have got to click "Toggle View" in the solution explorer tab[image: toggle view]

It swaps the view allowing you to see all the nitty gritty details that lightswitch normally hides from you (this has changed in RC2013)

Comment: Thanks, I can see the references now - although it seems they only show up for Lightswitch projects that are C# based, not VB.net based.   The problem remains that I can't see or add System.Data.SqlClient as a reference in a "using" or "imports" within the code.

Comment: Are you sure you have a reference to System.Data in your references? What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

you are probly trying to do this in the code of a screen (was my mistake atleast). But you need to prefrom this code in the code of your data base. Go to your logical view -> rmb on your dataBase name -> view code and voila there is where you need to implement the code. I hope it is usefull to you because it confused me at first too ;) and goodluck with your program

regards Corwin,

ps forgive me for my english, i've never been good at writing it.